# Questions about custom query operator

Tags: linq, f#

I'm working on a custom query provider and would like to support [SQL Server's recursive CTEs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). I have something that I think will work, but there are two improvements I'd like to make.

First, here's the signature of my query operator (mostly based on [`GroupJoin`](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/Query.fsi#L167-L171)).

```ml
type QueryBuilder with
    [<CustomOperation("recurse", IsLikeGroupJoin = true, JoinConditionWord = "on")>]
    member x.Recurse(
                    anchorSource: QuerySource<'Anchor, 'Q>,
                    recursiveSource: QuerySource<'Recursive, 'Q>,
                    anchorKeySelector: ('Anchor -> 'Key),
                    recursiveKeySelector: ('Recursive -> 'Key),
                    resultSelector: ('Anchor -> IQueryable<'Recursive> -> 'Result)) = 
                    Unchecked.defaultof<QuerySource<'Result, 'Q>>
```

And here's a sample query. Note the comment. The first improvement I'd like to make is prior range variables shouldn't be accessible afterwards. Is this possible?

```ml
query {
    for x in customQueryable do
    where (x.Day = 5)
    recurse y in customQueryable
        on (x.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays 1.0) = y) into g
    for z in g do
    //NOTE: `x` shouldn't be in scope here
    select x
}
```

The second improvement is, I'd prefer to use the query syntax below, but couldn't figure out how to pull it off.

```ml
query {
    for x in customQueryable do
    where (x.Day = 5)
    for y in customQueryable do
    recurseOn (x.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays 1.0) = y) into g
    for z in g do
    select z
}
```

I'm also wondering if this is possible.